# Mocking $http Data in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on an app that uses AngularJS. My app has a service that looks like this:

```
myApp.service('myService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
  this.getPicks = function() {
    /*
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      var picks = [];
      picks.push({ name: 'Test 1', id:1 });
      picks.push({ name: 'Test 2', id:2 });

      deferred.resolve(picks);
      return deferred.promise;
    */

    return $http.get('/api/getPicks');
  };
```

I'm calling this service by using the following call in my Controller:

```
return myService.getPicks();
```

This code worked when I was returning my hard-coded picks array. I was using that for testing purposes. Now, I'm trying to wire up to the REST API and its not working. I do not see any errors. At the same time, I do not see anything getting returned. My questions are:

```
1. Am I doing something wrong with my $http.get call?
2. How can I print out the result of the $http.get call?
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share how you're handling the response?  Remember that $http returns a deferred.

Answer (score 0):

You need to come up with a factory in this case when you wiring up a REST api call. Something like this:

```
myApp.factory('myService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
  return {
    getPicks: function() {
    /*
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      var picks = [];
      picks.push({ name: 'Test 1', id:1 });
      picks.push({ name: 'Test 2', id:2 });

      deferred.resolve(picks);
      return deferred.promise;
    */

    return $http.get('/api/getPicks');
  }
}]);
```

and in the controller you can inject this factory and call like this:

```
myService.getPicks().then(function(data){
//Code to handle response
});
```